# Subtract/divide values from different rows in the same group

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I don't know how to calculate the variance percentage of revenues from this year and the past year. In order to obtain the variance by percentage, I have to subtract two values from different rows.

Here is the demonstration of my report and the results that I wanted to obtain:

[image]

Comment: insert summary at Group by Source footer so u will get the total revenue for Source now create formula at row level as per the image attached the formula will be  ($1000/total revenue of source) * 100. for other group level you can apply the same logic

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your method but it is not working. The sum result is not correct. And I should've mentioned above for the variance % formular: ((current year - past year)/past year)x100